# Model.GetType().Name appended with what looks like GUID

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, proxy-classes

I'm doing a code first ASP .NET MVC project.

In my view, I'm taking in the entity.

```
@model MyProject.Model.MyEntity
```

Within the view I am rendering a partial view, passing in the model.

```
@Html.Partial("_Edit", Model)
```

In this partial view I have defined the model as an object.

```
@model object
```

When I display the model's type I get what appears to be a GUID appended to it.

```
@{
    Type entityType = Model.GetType();
    string singularName = entityType.Name;
}

@{ ViewBag.Title = "Edit an existing " + singularName; }
```

This is what I see on screen:

**Edit an existing MyEntity_CB3FF0C41867D7757E4AF90F10EE2F7ED5B407EFCB96592EC3FB0A06DCAB902B**

Anyone know why and is there a way around it other than doing a `SubString()` on the underscore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is rooted in Entity Framework rather than MVC x.

I ran into the same problem and printed out the fully qualified name of my model ("SupportContactSecurity"):

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SupportContactSecuri_4C68726A6CC129D0001F286F1E38612D8DEC28F26CA3D3884B53BCDF810D8E6A
```

**DynamicProxies** being the keyword there. Entity framework (by default) replaces your entities with these proxies so it can do change tracking at the context level (I think). If you want to turn this off, refer to [this Stack Exchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719787/programatically-enabling-disabling-entity-proxies).