# Code first - how can I save an ICollection when I'm not setting the parent object to EntityState.Modified?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

If I have the below class:

```
public class Foo()
{
public int PropertyIWantUpdated {get; set;}
public int PropertyIDontWantUpdated (get; set}

public ICollection<Bar> Bars {get; set;}
}
```

When saving to my db, instead of

```
context.Entry(thisFoo).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

I'm using

```
context.Entry(thisFood).Property(tf => tf.PropertyIWantUpdated).IsModified = true;
```

how can I also save changes to Bars?

Comment: Btw. CTP5 is obsolete. It has already final version called [Entity framework 4.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b41c728e-9b4f-4331-a1a8-537d16c6acdf&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 5):

It depends what you are trying to update. First of all let me clarify one important fact - if you have detached entity graph (more entities with relation) and you want to pass all changes to EF you are responsible for telling EF what has changed in every entity and every relation - EF will not help you with it.

If you are trying to update just `Bar` instances and you didn't change relations (= you didn't add new `Bar` to `Foo` or removed `Bar` from `Foo`) you just need to iterate `Bars` and set them to `Modified` state.

If you also changed content of `Bars` collection the whole process become really complicated and the approach depends on the way how you defined your entities = If you are using [independent or foreign key association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations/5282275#5282275).

In case of foreign key association (`Bar` has FK as property = in `Bar` you have something like `FooId`) you follows similar approach as at the beginning. You iterate `Bars` and set state to:

- `Modified` if an existing `Bar` was assigned to `Foo`
- `Added` if a new `Bar` was assigned to `Foo`

There is one big issue. If you removed some `Bar` instances from `Bars` collection you must also attach them to the context and set their state accordingly:

- `Modified` if FK should be set to null
- `Deleted` if `Bar` should be deleted

This all is only for one-to-many relations.

If you thought that previous approach was complicated be prepared that in case of independent association (`Bar` doesn't have FK property - always the case for many to many relations) the process is even worse. Independent associations have their own object tracking the state = setting the state on `Bar` entity doesn't persist new relation. The first problem is that this object is not directly accessible from DbContext API - you must convert `DbContext` to `ObjectContext` and use `ObjectStateManager` to get the access to `ObjectStateEntry` representing the relation. After that you must correctly set its state which is not as easy as it looks like because relation cannot be in `Modified` state - it can be only in `Unchanged`, `Added` or `Deleted`. It means that if you changed the Bar's relation from one to another `Foo` you must first find the old relation and set it as deleted and then you can set the new relation as added. If you have many-to-many relation and you also want to add, delete and update related objects (not only relations) this can be really "big fun" - especially the fact that you must somewhere keep the information what has changed to be able to set all states correctly.

More discussion about this problem (global in EF) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects/3635326#3635326) - it is not related to the DbContext API but because the new API is just wrapper of the old ObjectContext API same problems remain.

Do you think it is feasible? I don't think so. Because of that you should try to avoid this. There are some ways how to avoid it:

- Make changes on attached object graph - it means that you will first attach the original state of the entity graph to the context and then you will do all your changes.
- Load the original object graph and manually merge all changes from the new graph to the loaded (and attached) one.
- In case of ObjectContext API you can use [Self-tracking entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091974/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-tracking-entities/5092097#5092097) which are able to track the state and automatically set everything with applied to the context. They have some other [disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814706/self-tracking-entities-vs-poco-entities/3815968#3815968) and limitations (for example they don't support lazy loading) and they are not available for DbContext API.

Comment: I am using EF6 and if I add a new instance of `Bar` to `Bars` of a `Foo`; I simply set `Foo` to be modified and call `Save()` on `Foo`. Then it works as expected e.g. the new instance of `Bar` is saved to the `Bars` collection. I'm enforcing the foreign key between `Bars` and `Foo` e.g. there is a `FooId` on `Bars`. Is this the right way to do this? I can see that EF will first try to update `Foo` table (which is a waste as nothing is changed in the content of `Foo`) then create a new instance of `Bar` and add it to the `Bars` table.