# Entity Framework 4.1 detach scenario cascading update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I have worked with EF CTP4 and there wasnt any easy way how to perform cascading udate in detached scenario. Example: I have tree of elements which gets send from server to client (it gets detached). Client modifies this tree (properties and relations) and sends it back to server. Now I want to attach this tree and save it without much hustle.

My question is this posible in EF CTP5 and if not is it planned? Im wondering if EF will reach maturity of NHibernate where this is possible (where I can configure if I want cascading delete/update-save/none/etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is still not possible and as I know it is not planned. When working with detached entity graphs you are responsible for telling EF what has changed. EF 4.1 is just a wrapper for EF 4 so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects/3635326#3635326) is valid for DbContext API as well.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my worries and for the link ;) +1