# Entity Framework, Repository Pattern, Update in Detached Scenario

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'm trying to update an object graph that contains ICollection of modified/added/deleted entities in a detached scenario (short lived context), using EF 5.0?

I have something like this:

```
Visit (Edited)    
    FinancialInfo (Unchanged)
          Discount1 (Added)
          Discount2 (Modified)
          Discount3 (Deleted)
```

When I try to update visit it throws OptimisticConcurrency exception:

> "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries."

Actually I know what is causing the problem, but I'm using a repository pattern, I do not use DbContext directly.

I could write custom update logic for Visit entity which would handle the issue, but I'm looking for a generic option.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6993989/896276) makes me think that, probably there's no hustle free approach, but anyway...

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I did this at this point:

I overrided the Update method of my base repository class and wrote custom logic about handling objects in the update tree. I followed [this example](http://entityframeworktutorial.net/update-one-to-many-entities-in-entity-framework.aspx)

I don't like this solution but I hope EF will become more flexible in the near future. Thanks for your attention,.