# update with entity framework self tracking entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having a problem that I thought was easy to resolve.
This is my scenario (Entity framework 4 disconnected entities using self tracking).
Let's say I have 2 entities: Users, Orders.
From an asp.net page a get from the database 1 user and 1 order.

```
const int userId = 1;
const int orderId = 1;
var userManager = new UserManager();
var orderManager = new OrderManager();
var user = userManager.GetUser(userId);
var order = channelManager.GetChannel(channelId);

user.Orders.Add(order);
```

Now I need to create a function that updates the user adding the order to it.

I wrote something like:

```
public bool UpdateUser(User user)
{
    context.AttachTo("Users", user);

    var stateMgr = context.ObjectStateManager;
    var stateEntry = stateMgr.GetObjectStateEntry(user);

    for (int i = 0; i < stateEntry.CurrentValues.FieldCount; i++)
    {
            bool isKey = false;

            string name = stateEntry.CurrentValues.GetName(i);

            foreach (var keyPair in stateEntry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues)
            {
                    if (string.Compare(name, keyPair.Key, true) == 0)
                    {
                            isKey = true;
                            break;
                    }
            }
            if (!isKey)
            {
                    stateEntry.SetModifiedProperty(name);
            }
    } 

    context.ApplyCurrentValues("Users", user);

    return context.SaveChanges() > 0;
}
```

I don't have any error on this function and debugging everything seems to be ok, but when I check on the database the entity is not updated as expected.
I thought update a disconnected entity was something simple but apparently is not.
Can someone explaing me the logic between the update the entire graph of disconnected object with EF4? Please if you can I need to undestand the logic and not have a collection of links to look at. I already spent some time looking on internet but I'm finding so many approches that I'm not sure which one is correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything related to Self tracking entities in your code. Anyway STEs with ASP.NET [don't work very well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814706/self-tracking-entities-vs-poco-entities/3815968#3815968).

What is your code supposed to do? It looks like you want to do this:

```
public bool UpdateUser(User user)
{
    context.AttachTo("Users", user);
    context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user, EntityState.Modified);
    return context.SaveChanges() > 0;
}
```

But it [will not save relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects/3635326#3635326). I just answered some [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804491/reattaching-an-entity-graph-and-detecting-collection-changes/7804814#7804814) about working with detached graphs.

Answer (score 0):

With Self Tracking Entities you have to use the ApplyChanges() method to sync the change on a context instead (and not attach).

The applychanges will go to the graph to update the linked object/collection.

```
 Public Function UpdateEntity(entity As Entity) As Entity

    Using dbContext As New EntityContext()
        dbContext.EntitySet.ApplyChanges(entity)
        dbContext.SaveChanges()

        dbContext.Refresh(Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, entity)
    End Using

    Return entity 
End Function
```

The refresh is optionnal, it is here only to push back the last value of the database. By the way the refresh doesn't update the linked object.