# how to copy data in following case

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have 2 objects, one is linked to datacontext, second is not. I need to copy full data from second to first. How to do it? If I try just

```
obj1 = obj2;
```

I got error about EntityDataContext is not attached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EF framework has many levels and versions by now. When you're using an ObjectContext you can use [ApplyCurrentValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487246.aspx#Y0) :

```
T ApplyCurrentValues<T>(string entitySetName, T currentEntity)
```

Comment: +1 This is correct answer but it will work only for scalar and complex properties. It will not handle navigation properties and EF has [no automatic solution for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects/3635326#3635326).