# EF detect changes in detached object graph by ObjectContext

Tags: entity-framework

Is exists way to detect changes in one object graph comparing it this another object graph.

For example:

```
usersSourceGraph = ObjectContext.Users.Where("bla bla bla");
userGraph = GetUsersGraph() // come from another tier and detached from ObjectContext.
```

I need way of setting userGraph states in (Modified,New) comparing with usersSourceGraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do it [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects/3635326#3635326). There is no support in EF for merging two object graphs.

Comment: It bit confusing me. Why EF doesn't support such feature.