# How to set navigation property in Entity Framework 6 in case of generic entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have update a generic update method as follows

```
public virtual void Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity, string modifiedBy = 
null)           where TEntity : class,IEntity
{
  using (var context = new BanyanDbContext())
  {                
    entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    entity.ModifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    var existingEntiy = context.Set<TEntity>().Find(entity.Id);
    context.Entry(existingEntiy).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
    context.Entry(existingEntiy).State = EntityState.Modified;                                
    Save(context);
  }
}
```

This method is working fine for updating non reference type values, but `CurrentValues.SetValues()` does not set or update navigation properties. 
How can I set navigation property in this scenario.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705569/using-the-entrytentity-currentvalues-setvalues-is-not-updating-collections?

Answer (score 0):

```
public TEntity RemoveNavigationProperties(TEntity input)
        {

            foreach (var item in input.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType.Namespace == input.GetType().Namespace))
            {
                item.SetValue(input, null);
            }

            return input;
        }
```

This worked for me. (I just needed to null them)