# Entity framework - persisting a graph of POCO entities

Tags: entity-framework

In my app I need to retrieve a large graph of entities, make various changes *while detached* (add entities, make changes, delete entities), then persist the graph back to the database. I've tried STEs but it's starting to over-complicate some aspects of my client tier, so I was hoping to keep things simple (at least on the client side) by using POCOs instead.

When it comes to persisting the changes, I was thinking I could retrieve the graph from the database again, and walk both this graph and the graph from the client tier, looking for differences:-

- A deletion is actioned where an entity exists in the database graph but not the client graph. Presumably I can just `.Remove()` these from the database graph.
- New entities are those in the client graph with an ID of 0. Presumably I can just `.Add()` these to the database graph.
- I'm not sure the best way to deal with updates. I don't want to implement an "IsDirty" flag on my entities, and would prefer a more automatic solution. So a) is there a way to compare an entity in the client graph with its database counterpart to see if it has changed, and b) what's the best way of applying/merging the client entity into its database counterpart?

Once all this is done I presumably just call SaveChanges() on the database graph. I would also have to pass this graph back to the client, to ensure it has the latest version (database-generated values such as IDs, timestamps).

Is my solution too simplistic? If it's feasible, how can I deal with updates as outlined above?

Comment: This is a broad subject. I suggest you find a copy of Lerman & Miller's book _DbContext_ and read through chapter 4 on how to work with disconnected entities. Their proposed approach is to implement an interface `IObjectWithState` which makes object track their own change state. I can't say it's really elegant, but maybe more generic than traversing a specific object graph yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution can work but it is not simple thing to implement - especially if you try to do it somehow generic (check answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects) - somebody offered a code base which should have this already implemented). It also causes a lot of additional traffic to database so it is definitely not a good approach when you expect some heavy load. The simplest solution is what @Gert Arnold mentioned.

Comment: I've had a try of the Lerman approach, and while it works, it's a lot of work in the BLL as I'm using a very large hierarchy. It also makes the client more complex, as relationship fix-up is more involved, amongst other things. It's only a 2-tier WCF app, so I'm rethinking my approach. If you can spare a few minutes to reply please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790286/poco-entities-in-a-2-tier-wcf-application