# POCO entities in a 2-tier WPF application

Tags: entity-framework

I need to retrieve a large graph of entities, manipulate it in the UI (adds, updates, deletes), then persist it all back to the database. After various SO questions and experiments, I'm finding this mass "detached graph update" approach to be very problematic, so I'm now rethinking my approach.

It's only a 2-tier WPF app, so I'm now thinking of having a long-running context that exists for the duration of the UI used to manipulate the entity graph - that way it can track changes automatically. However I'm not sure how to approach this architecturally.

The application currently has three projects - the UI, business tier, and one for the edmx & generated entities. My business tier has a `CustomerManager` class that exposes a method to retrieve a Customer graph (orders, order lines, etc.), and a method to persist the Customer graph. Assuming that the UI holds on to the same instance of the `CustomerManager` class, and therefore the same context, changes to the graph (adding and changing entities) will be tracked.

Deleting an entity is a bit more tricky, as the context must be used to do this, i.e.:-

```
context.Set<Order>().Remove(orderToDelete);
```

Looking for some architectural advice really. Do I just expose a `DeleteOrder` method in my `CustomerManager` class that does this? Given that I have a dozen other entity types, I would presumably need to expose similar methods to delete orders, products, etc.

Is it a sensible approach for the UI to hold on to the same `CustomerManager` instance, or is there a better way to manage a long-running context? A logical place for the `DeleteOrder` method would be in my Customer entity (partial) class, but as these classes are in a separate project from the business tier (which is where the context resides), I guess I can't do this (unless I pass the context to the DeleteOrder method)?

Comment: For fully disconnected scenario you need 2nd level cache. EF doesn't have one out of the box. (NHibernate does). This article can help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394143.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your long living context idea will work only if your context lives in UI and UI talks to database directly to get and persist data. Involving WCF between your UI and context always result in serialization and it causes entity detaching = not tracking changes (unless you use STEs). Having long living context in WCF service is too problematic and in general bad practice.

Have you considered WCF Data Services? They provide client side tracking to some extend by using special client side context.

Comment: Many apologies, I meant to say it's a "2-tier WPF" (not WCF) application. Having a bad day - I've updated the question.

Comment: Ok. In case of WPF application using detached entity graphs don't make sense. Use context with lifetime bounded by some UI area and work with attached entities. Detached entity graphs are for scenarios like web applications and web services.

Comment: Is it acceptable to directly access a context from (say) a viewmodel, or would you have it in a BLL class (even though it's only a "logical" tier), similar to what I described?

Comment: It depends on complexity of the logic. Sometimes it is enough to have it referenced directly and sometimes it is better to encapsulate the logic to separate layer (logical tier).