# How do I get original values for a navigation collection property, in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

My EF Core entity:

```
public class Order {
    public string Code { get; set; }  
    public ICollection<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }  
}
```

I can get the original value for the `Code` property using:

```
context.Entry(myOrder).OriginalValues["Code"]
```

But if I try that for the `LineItems` navigation collection property, then it throws with:

`The property LineItems on entity type Order is being accessed using the 'Property' method, but is defined in the model as a navigation property. Use either the 'Reference' or 'Collection' method to access navigation properties.`

That exception message doesn't refer to methods I can find.

So how do I get original values for a navigation collection property?

Comment: Look at the methods of `context.Entry(myOrder)`.

Comment: Use context.Entry(myOrder).Collection("LineItems") as mentioned in exception

Comment: @grokky you want to get the current  collection of order that saved in the database ?

Comment: @FooVirus Not the "current" collection, but the "original" collection. The original values before any changes. I thought the change tracker tracked collections just like it tracks non-collections.

Comment: @grokky  context.Enty(myOrder).Collection(x => x.LineItems).CurrentValue : Gets  current value of the navigation property Or use  context.Enty(myOrder).Collection(x => x.LineItems).Load() to get original dbvalue but if entities that already exist in the context are not overwritten with values from the database.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects/3635326#3635326 ,i think this may help you

Comment: Nope it doesn't take a lambda, and besides, Load() doesn't load the old entities. It's the original/old ones I need.

Comment: Have you found a way to get the original values from the navigation property?